# Vue JS - how to set default value from JSON into dynamically created UI fields?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

We are iterating through a JSON object and setting the UI fields dynamically, using the  tag. That works fine. However, there is one attribute in that JSON object, "value" that we wish to use to set the default value of those UI fields, such as a default text in a TextInput. What attribute should we set in the "component" tag to achieve this ? Appreciate your help in getting this done.

```
            <div v-for="(form, index) in forms"
                 :key="index"
                 v-bind="form"
                 class="form__group">
                <label class="form__label" v-model="form.label">{{ form.label }}</label>
                <component :is="form.fieldType"
                           :currentField="form"
                           class="form__field">
                </component>
            </div>
```

Comment: I see "component", am guessing that's where you want to show the "value".

Comment: Yes, correct. That tag gets replaced by the actual UI control based on the "form.fieldType" - such as TextInput, TextArea etc. But am not able to figure out where to specify the default value.

Comment: Well, you need to know/learn more about your "component", does it have config options, can you see it's code?

Comment: It is the built-in component tag, I see documentation on it but only about the ":is" attribute and nothing else. This is one such reply from another post - You can use a built-in component element like so:

<component is="ul" class="foo" style="color:red">
  anything inside component
</component>

Comment: Another link: https://alligator.io/vuejs/dynamic-components/

Comment: I think I found out - will have to add the default value to the property of the underlying Vue Component that is being bound to the UI field using "v-bind".

Comment: Yes, the component tag renders components with the name from "form.fieldType", so those surely take defaults... don't forget to post an answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON node that is being passed to the component through ":currentField='form'" should be used to set the default value. Like this-

```
<el-input
      type="text"
      v-model="form.value">
</el-input> 
<script>    
  export default {
    name: 'TextInput',
    props: ['form']
  }
</script>
```

Thanks to @kitschmaster for directing my thoughts properly